# Group by and find count before doing pivot spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have a dataframe like below

```
A   B   C       D
foo one small   1
foo one large   2
foo one large   2
foo two small   3
```

I need to `groupBy` based on A and B `pivot` on column C, and `sum` column D

I am able to do this using

```
df.groupBy("A", "B").pivot("C").sum("D")
```

However I need also to find `count` after `groupBy` ,if I try something like

```
df.groupBy("A", "B").pivot("C").agg(sum("D"), count)
```

I get an output like

```
A   B   large   small large_count small_count
```

Is there a way to get only one `count` after `groupBy` before doing `pivot`

Answer (score 0):

On output try

output.withColumn("count", $"large_count"+$"small_count").show

You can drop the two count columns if you want to

To do it before pivot try
df.groupBy("A", "B").agg(count("C"))

Comment: I cant do `df.groupBy("A", "B").agg(count("C"))` as pivot is applicable on grouped by data only

Comment: Can you post what you want your output to look like? Not sure what you exactly want here

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?.

```
val df = Seq(("foo", "one", "small",   1),
("foo", "one", "large",   2),
("foo", "one", "large",   2),
("foo", "two", "small",   3)).toDF("A","B","C","D")

scala> df.show
+---+---+-----+---+
|  A|  B|    C|  D|
+---+---+-----+---+
|foo|one|small|  1|
|foo|one|large|  2|
|foo|one|large|  2|
|foo|two|small|  3|
+---+---+-----+---+

scala> val df2 = df.groupBy('A,'B).pivot("C").sum("D")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: string, B: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> val df3 = df.groupBy('A as "A1",'B as "B1").agg(sum('D) as "sumd")
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A1: string, B1: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df3.join(df2,'A==='A1 and 'B==='B1,"inner").select("A","B","sumd","large","small").show
+---+---+----+-----+-----+
|  A|  B|sumd|large|small|
+---+---+----+-----+-----+
|foo|one|   5|    4|    1|
|foo|two|   3| null|    3|
+---+---+----+-----+-----+


scala>
```

Comment: what if my dataframe size is very large, doing group by and join will have huge impact on performance

Comment: that depends on the uniqueness of the cols A and B together. Give a try!

Answer (score 0):

This wont require a join. Is this what you are looking for ?

```
val df = Seq(("foo", "one", "small",   1),
("foo", "one", "large",   2),
("foo", "one", "large",   2),
("foo", "two", "small",   3)).toDF("A","B","C","D")

scala> df.show
+---+---+-----+---+
|  A|  B|    C|  D|
+---+---+-----+---+
|foo|one|small|  1|
|foo|one|large|  2|
|foo|one|large|  2|
|foo|two|small|  3|
+---+---+-----+---+

df.registerTempTable("dummy")

spark.sql("SELECT * FROM (SELECT A , B , C , sum(D) as D from dummy group by A,B,C grouping sets ((A,B,C) ,(A,B)) order by A nulls last , B nulls last , C nulls last) dummy pivot (first(D) for C in ('large' large ,'small' small , null total))").show

+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  A|  B|large|small|total|
+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
|foo|one|    4|    1|    5|
|foo|two| null|    3|    3|
+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
```